# Randomize a Weekly Schedule

Tags: excel

I have a list that repeats every day. In order randomize the list I have two columns in excel the first column has names and the second list uses `=rand()` to create a random seed. I then organize the two columns from smallest to largest based on the seed in the second column. Is there a way to enter the list of items in one column and than get seven randomized versions of the list?

Comment: The problem with random lists of the sort you describe is that they are too random. Random means that the same person could get the "Monday" job 3 weeks in a row and another never got any job in six months. I recommend you create a good algorithm instead which ensures that everybody does a fair share of the work and/or gets a fair share of the rewards.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Clustering isn't a problem. Truly random lists are fine, we'd just like to be able to put in the items in the list once, instead of having to do a bunch of copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try this. Start by writing your names in a named range. I called it `NameList` but any other name will be just as good. This list can be anywhere in your workbook and it can have any number of names in it. Now, at the heart of your formula is this function.

```
=INT(RAND()*COUNTA(NameList)+1)
```

It returns a random number between 1 and the number of names in your list. This you embed in an INDEX() function to return a random name from that list.

```
=INDEX(NameList,INT(RAND()*COUNTA(NameList)+1))
```

You can make as many lists as you like, anywhere in the workbook, just by copying the formula to one cell and down from there for as long as you want your list to be, shorter or longer than `NameList` doesn't matter.

The only problem you will have, other than clustering, is that your lists all change very time the worksheet decides it wants to recalculate. You might set `Calculation` to "Manual" but that applies to all of Excel, including even other workbooks. I have been wondering if you might use the option *Automatic except for data tables* but didn't try it. The safest way should be to simply `Copy / Paste Special` to replace all formulas with their hard values. If you choose that option, make sure you keep a copy of the formula safe somewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. I created a list of names that I wanted to randomly order in the B column with Sunday as the heading. Sometimes we have more names, sometimes we have less so I made two open slots incase I needed to add somebody. The next column I called Order Seed column and I used `=RAND()` to give me a random value. Now in the Monday through Saturday columns I make the cell = the numbered cell from Sunday. In this case the E2 cell `=B3` and the E4 cell `=B4`. When I want to randomize the list for Monday I select the Number column, the Day column and the Order Seed. I then sort by the Order Seed. This rearranges the names for me. If I want to change the order again I just resort by the Order Seed column.

Answer (score 0):

To shuffle the list without using sort and avoid duplicate items, you can use RANDBETWEEN, RANK and INDEX function. Suppose "NameList" is the name of your list.

The RANDBETWEEN function returns a random number between 1 and the count of items in your list. You need to add ROW()/10000 to avoid duplicates.

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(NameList))+ROW()/10000
```

Then you use RANK function to find the rank of each random numbers.

```
=RANK(B3,$B$3:$B$6)
```

Finally, you need to use INDEX function to retrieve the item name from list.

```
=INDEX(NameList,C3)
```

[image]

You need to repeat this for each day of the week. I agree, it would be better if we did not require the extra columns (B and C).

Reference:
https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/shuffle-list/